# Add a path to /etc/paths.d/ referring to whatever logged in users home directory

Tags: bash, osx, bsd

I found this cool trick from Postgres.app website

```
echo /Users/user1/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

I want to know, how can I make this work for **any** logged in user.
I want something like

```
echo {whatever the home directory of the logged in user at runtime}/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

My first thought was to try the `$HOME` variable, but my home variable points
to my home directory, whereas I want this to work when any user logs in to Mac and uses terminal.app.

Comment: "My first thought was to try the $HOME variable, but my home variable points to my home directory, whereas I want this to work when any user logs in to Mac and uses terminal.app."  Um, what?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell by experiment, the answer is that you can't do that with `$HOME`, but there are other ways.

`HOME` contains the current user's path (remember that the environment is per-process), so the obvious attempt would be to create a file that contains `$HOME/latest/bin` without expanding it when adding the line. (i.e. if on the command line `echo '$HOME/blah...'` with single quotes.)

Then we'd hope that the shell would interpolate that when reading those files and setting the path. But this doesn't work, as  `path-helper`, the tool that uses `/etc/paths.d`, seems to escape the dollar sign:

```
$ cat /etc/paths.d/test 
$HOME/test
$ PATH="" /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:\$HOME/test"; export PATH;
```

So you'll get a literal dollar sign in the path.

---

If you only care about Bash, you could use the tilde (`~`) in place of `$HOME`. It's not escaped, and works to refer to the home directory in `PATH`. But it doesn't work with `ksh` so `zsh`, so this isn't universal solution.

---

Instead, you could add the directory to the path manually in `/etc/profile`. (Or in `/etc/zprofile` for `zsh`.)

On my system, `/etc/profile` has this snippet setting the path given by `path_helper`:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Add the `PATH` assignment somewhere in the file:

```
PATH="$HOME/latest/bin:$PATH"
```

If you put the line after the call to `path_helper`, the directory will be at the head of your part, if you put it before `path_helper`, `path_helper` seems to move it to the end of resulting path.

Comment: Tilde in PATH breaks PATH for ksh and  zsh in sh or ksh emulation mode.

Comment: @fd0, I wasn't even sure at first if it would work in Bash. Thanks for confirming about the others.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '$HOME/latest/bin' | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```